# Bootstrap 4 Carousel controls not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Never had this issue before, but for whatever reason my carousel controls for a basic BS4 carousel are not working. Interestingly enough, the indicators are working when they are clicked?

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="embed-container">
                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/..." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="embed-container">
                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/..." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="embed-container">
                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/..." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding the `popper.js` may help you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="embed-container">
                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/..." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="embed-container">
                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/..." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="embed-container">
                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/..." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in Bootstrap 4 `item` is no longer used. it's now `carousel-item` according to the docs.