# Carousel control not working in bootstrap version 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, jquery-3

I am using bootstrap version 4. But My Carousel control is not working. Am I missing any thing? 
**Same below code is working perfectly fine If i change version to 3.4**

Please help me here.

PFB are JS files I included. Same JS files are working fine if i change the version to 3.4.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

PFB Bootstrap Carousel control example which I am using.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel2&stacked=h

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4 "item" is no longer used. it's now carousel-item according to the Bootstrap 4.

PFB have working solution for Bootstrap 4.

[Bootstrap 4 Carousel controls not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47820156/bootstrap-4-carousel-controls-not-working)